# Why Discover does not load packages in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, kde, kde5

When I tried to run Discover, I got this error message:

> #### Unable to load applications
>
> Please verify Internet connectivity

And when I ran it in terminal, I got (stdout & stderr):

```
fetch ratings! false
adding empty sources model QStandardItemModel(0x55bb25b77ea0)
no component found for "org.kali.kali"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
```

My sources.list file:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

Why this error is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KDE Discover](https://apps.kde.org/discover/) is a software management UI, which makes it inherently distro-specific.

Kali simply isn't supported by it, so you can't make it work short of programming it to be.

I really don't see why you'd ever need a graphical software center on Kali Linux. If you need that, Kali is probably simply the [wrong Linux distribution for your current use case](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/), and you should use literally almost any other Linux distro:

> - If you are new to **Linux** or have less experience with **command line** you might find Kali Linux to be not so user-friendly, even though our developers try to make it as user-friendly as possible some things might be intimidating to you if you are new.

Comment: I need discover to find apps by categories. Is there a solution to do this using apt only?

Comment: sure, dpkg has package groups, though *Kali really doesn't do any more sensible grouping than debian does*, and is generally not meant for this kind of adminstrative approach. `aptitude` is a nice and easy way of interacting with these. Anyways, wanting categories **really is** a strong indication that you *should not be using Kali for your current work* and instead just use debian. All the things installed in your default Kali are also there on debian, but, they just actually work for a user, instead of being optimized for a pentester.

Comment: Note how that link I supplied is not by people who don't like Kali, it is *by Kali authors themselves*. Really read it critically and think whether it might describe what you're trying to do as something that you *don't* use Kali for.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linux distribution geared towards various information security tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux. This is unwise.